# Using Django FormPreview the right way

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

## My Goal

I have a django project with a form, and I want to display a preview page before the user submits.

## The problem

I can display a preview page using a Django [FormPreview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-preview/), but not all form data is displayed properly. Specifically, if I have a field with `choices`, the string values of these choices aren't displayed.  I'm also having problems applying template filters to date fields.  The end result is that some data on the preview page is visible but other data is blank:

[image: Preview page]

However, if I display the same data for posts that have actually been submitted, then everything displays properly:

[image: Submitted page]

## My Code

**models.py**:

```
class Game(models.Model):

  # Game Choices
  FOOTBALL = 0
  BASKETBALL = 1
  TENNIS = 2
  OTHER = 3
  GAME_CHOICES = (
      (FOOTBALL, 'Football'),
      (BASKETBALL, 'Basketball'),
      (TENNIS, 'Tennis'),
      (OTHER, 'Other')
    )

  game_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Location")
  game = models.IntegerField(choices=GAME_CHOICES, default=FOOTBALL)
  game_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Game Date')
```

**forms.py**

```
class GameForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Game
    fields = (
      'location',
      'game',
      'game_date'
    )
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem is in my views.py: I'm not sure that I'm processing the `POST` request the right way to feed all data to the preview page.

**views.py**

```
def form_upload(request):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    form = GameForm()
  else:
    # A POST request: Handle Form Upload
    form = GameForm(request.POST) # Bind data from request.POST into a GameForm
    # If data is valid, proceeds to create a new game and redirect the user
    if form.is_valid():
      game = form.save()
      return render(request, 'games/success.html', {})
  return render(request, 'games/form_upload.html', {
    'form': form,
  })
```

**preview.py**

```
class GameFormPreview(FormPreview):

  form_template = 'games/form_upload.html'
  preview_template = 'games/preview.html'

  def done(self, request, cleaned_data):
    # Do something with the cleaned_data, then redirect
    # to a "success" page.
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/games/success')
```

**form_upload.html**

```
...
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <ul><li>{{ form.as_p }}</li></ul>

  <button type="submit">Preview your post</button>
</form>
...
```

**preview.html**

```
{% load humanize %}
...
<h1>Preview your submission</h1>

  <div>
    <p>Location: {{ form.data.location }}</p>
    <p>Game Date: {{ form.data.game_date|date:"l, F d, Y" }}</p>
    <p>Game Type: {{ form.data.get_game_display }}</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <form action="{% url 'form_upload' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
      {{ field.as_hidden }}
      {% endfor %}
      <input type="hidden" name="{{ stage_field }}" value="2" />
      <input type="hidden" name="{{ hash_field }}" value="{{ hash_value }}" />

      <!-- Submit button -->
      <button type="submit">Submit your post</button>
      <!-- Go back button -->
      <button type="submit">
        <a href="{% url 'form_upload' %}" 
          onClick="history.go(-1);return false;" >
          Go back and edit your post
        </a>
      </button>

      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
...
```

## Two issues

Essentially, I'm having these two issues:

1. String values for `choices` are not displayed. If I use the [get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method in my `preview.html` template, it returns blank. However, if I use this in a page after the post has been submitted, it displays properly.
2. The `humanize` date filter doesn't work.  If I apply a `humanize` filter (`{{ form.data.game_date|date:"l, F d, Y" }}`) in `preview.html`, it also displays blank.  Again, this works for submitted posts.

My question essentially is: what's the right way to use the `FormPreview` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.data` does not have `get_FOO_display` attributes. When you access `{{ form.data.get_game_display }}` in the template, it fails silently and doesn't display anything.

The `get_FOO_display` are methods of the instance, so try this instead.

```
{{ form.instance.get_game_display }}
```

Wherever possible you should access data from [`form.cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) (which is validated and 'cleaned') instead of `form.data`, which is the raw data submitted to the form.

The filters don't work with `form.data.game_date` because it's a raw string. They should work with `form.cleaned_data.game_date`, which has been converted to a python date object.

Finally, you haven't implemented anything in your `done` method, you've just copied the comment from the docs. You could create a new game using `cleaned_data` as follows:

```
def done(self, request, cleaned_data):
    game = Game.objects.create(**cleaned_data)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/games/success')
```

Comment: This is excellent! Thanks! None of the documentation I found about using `FormPreview` had this info -- really good to know!  Do you know if there is a good resource to read about this that I just missed?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any resources about `FormPreview` in particular. The difference between `form.data` and `form.cleaned_data` concerns forms in general, not just `FormPreview`. Similarly, being able to access `form.instance` is a feature of regular model forms.