# Django FormPreview: Save form data to database

Tags: python, django

Probably a simple question but having trouble implementing a form preview page using django-formtools. I've configured everything per the docs. I'm stuck on what to add to the `done()` method to save the data to db.

forms.py

```
class JobForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('title', 'category', 'company', 'website',    'description',)

class JobFormPreview(FormPreview):
    def done(self, request, cleaned_data):
        # add what here to save form data as object?
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success')
```

urls.py

```
...
url(r'^jobs/new/$',
    JobFormPreview(JobForm),
    name='job_form'),
...
```

Using the default templates. The form and preview both render fine, but obviously data doesn't save on submit. Tried `self.form.save()` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31559444/6824523) but get an error `save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [formtools code](https://github.com/django/django-formtools/blob/171e3c63a0246fb5b955dfc0fc017e480969256f/formtools/preview.py#L21), it looks as if `self.form` is the form class, not the validated form instance. Therefore `self.form.save()` will not work. I've removed the suggestion to call `self.form.save()` from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31559444/6824523).

I can't see a straight forward way to access the validated form in the `done` method. I suggest that you create the instance using the `cleaned_data` instead:

```
class JobFormPreview(FormPreview):
    def done(self, request, cleaned_data):
        job = Job.objects.create(**cleaned_data)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success')
```